# Apostrophe or assume the possessive?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, proper-nouns

This question has divided the office into two camps.  Camp 1 believes the correct way to indicate the relationship in this sentence is to use the client's name as a possessive, as in "When UltraGalactic's employees call the Customer Service line..."  Camp 2 believes the apostrophe can be dropped because "UltraGalactic" is modifying "employees," and therefore the possessive is assumed. Frankly, I don't understand the uproar over typing two additional characters, but I'd appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 9):

Both are grammatically correct.

> UltraGalactic's employees...

Indicates that the employees belong to UltraGalactic.

and

> UltraGalactic employees

Indicates that employees are employees at UltraGalactic.